# How to write query sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 objects, `OPP` and `Order`.

Opp is parent and Order is child objects/Tables. Opp has column `amount` and order has column `Sum`.

I want a SQL query which can do the summation of all sum(columns) and match with Amount on Opp and show only those records which match.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: And also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Join parent against sub-query calculating the sum of the child rows

```
SELECT p.*
FROM OPP p
JOIN (SELECT parent_id, SUM(amount) total 
      FROM Order
      GROUP BY parent_id) as c ON c.parent_id = p.id
WHERE c.total = p.amount
```

I assume OPP has a identifier `id` and Order a foreign key `parent_id`. I used Int for amount columns but if you have some kind of floating value you might need to round your values.